# get range error in .sum() in sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am using .sum() to get total in sequelise and it works but it throw an error suppose I have table name "fruits" which has two column

**name:-** *apple, mango, strawberry*

**qty:-** *25, 50, 25*

here is my code :-

```
fruits.sum('qty').then(function (totalQty) {
        console.log('total============================',totalQty);
        res.send(totalQty)
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err)
        res.send(err)
    })
```

it returns *" total========================100 "*
which is perfect but it also give the range error and i don't understand why this is happening

> ERROR:-
>
> total============================ 0
>
> RangeError[ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: 0

please help me out ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i solved the problem this is deu to complex format which sequelize return you just nead to send the responce in object this is updated code

```
fruits.sum('qty').then(function (totalQty) {
    console.log('total============================',totalQty);
    res.send({total:totalQty})
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err)
    res.send(err)
})
```